# CSS inlining error: DOMXPath::query(): Invalid expression in selector in Magento 2.2.5

Tags: email, email-templates, magento-2.2.5, dom

In magento 2.2.5, I am using the custom theme and I have used the blank theme's files. In mail I am getting this error :

> CSS inlining error: DOMXPath::query(): Invalid expression in selector
>   input[type="text"] in /root/vendor/pelago/emogrifier/Classes/Emogrifier.php on line 372.

I have tried these solutions:
1. [link 1](http://awebtech.blogspot.com/2016/10/css-inline-error-warning-domxpathquery.html)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the late reply. But maybe it will help someone.

On Magento 2.2.5 you can use the following workaround:

create the files

`/web/css/email.less`

`/web/css/email-inline.less`

in your custom theme and add the content from

`/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/email.less` and
`/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/email-inline.css`
 respectively. But each with the line "@import 'source/_theme.less';" commented out (or removed)

still works with Magento 2.2.7

Comment: what is the meaning of this line ?
but each with the line "@import 'source/_theme.less';" commented out (or removed);

Comment: what I wanted to say with that was: copy the complete content of /vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/email.less and
/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/email-inline.css to the files in your theme and remove the line "@import 'source/_theme.less" from each.

Answer (score 1):

I only had this issue when running Client side less compilation in Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Frontend Development Workflow.

Switching back to Server side less compilation fixed the issue and the less compiled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same issue:
i used the  php version is 7.3  (**Which is the main issue**).
i just downgrade the php version 7.3 to 7.2 . Everything is working fine :)